# Add disks to encrypted LVM partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, security, encryption

If I increase my current encrypted (dm-crypt)LVM partition by adding another disk to it, is the new disk also encrypted or do I need to setup dm-crypt on it as well?

Comment: It depends how your volumes are set up, and you didn't tell us that. Post the output of `lsblk`, and tell us how you're planning to use that new disk.

Comment: I have simple set up ubuntu using lvm and encryption from the installer and then later i added a disk to my home group. I sadly don't have the laptop with me at the moment so i can't post my lsblk